# Using of Session Database on multiple Apache Servers

Tags: php, database, apache, class, session

I have been working on a webApp which should be able to perform tasks only by using AJAX. It seems to work pretty good, but I am running into a problem, because I do not store `Session` variables on the public site.

My login procedure is similar to iCloud's. You arrive to one page asking for a login. Your login is sent to a server using AJAX and returns a `true` or `false`. If true, the login box disappears and you are ready to work with the applications.

[image]

When you Are looking at the image above, you shall see the two green boxes as the exact same site, without any URL refreshes or anything. It is simply the same page.

The Pink boxes represents Apache Servers that hasn't registered any `Sessions`. My Session Class has been builded using the `session_set_save_handler` idea.

```
session_set_save_handler(
         array($this, 'open'),
         array($this, 'close'),
         array($this, 'read'),
         array($this, 'write'),
         array($this, 'destroy'),
         array($this, 'gc')
     );
```

I can't seem to figure out a way for the public site to ask for data on the `pink` servers without a Session ID. Could anybody tell me the idea behind the `session_set_save_handler` idea as if I was 6 years old? I have read the PHP manual for details, but it really confuses me.

If anybody knows about how this communication method could work properly, please tell me. All of the Apache Servers are connected through a LAN network, and are able to communicate. Also they all have access to the same `Session Class` in an Apache include Library.

Comment: I suggest to serialize / deserialize `$_SESSION` and store it within `Sessions` table.

Comment: But how will an Apache server know which Session to handle during a request?

Comment: When I haven't misread: you save the new session into a table - in a central place - from where every apache server can read it?

Comment: exactly.. My confusion is how the apache server should know which of the sessions it should handle

Comment: @PhilipJensBramsted you save the data in a cookie (which `session_start()` automatically sets?)

Comment: I don't know what kind of variable I can send through AJAX so that the Apache Server knows which `row` in the Session DB to look for

Comment: Via `PHPSESSID` / `COOKIE`. How about session prediction with peaceful intentions?

Comment: @bwoebi Can I access them using AJAX when it is set to HTTP_ONLY?

Comment: @PhilipJensBramsted Yes. (HTTP_ONLY is a protection against direct reading by Javascript, but not for ajax (which will send it automatically))

Comment: So PHP sets a cookie variable for HTTP_ONLY and I can through Javascript get the Cookie, place it in my AJAX request, and then execute the function? And there is no security risk during that?

Comment: Nono. Ajax sends the cookie automatically. You cannot read it by Javascript.

Comment: @bwoebi That was also what confused me.. So AJAX automatically sends the php cookie variables.. That is actually kind of cool..

Comment: But doesn't that require that the Cookie Variable has been set on the public site? or can I use the `session_set_cookie_params()` for that?

Comment: I think I got it, but for future Views, could Anybody please specify an answer?

Comment: Just flag what helps as **useful**.

Comment: @bwoebi How should it work, since there is no refresh after login. How does the public site on Server 1, know the cookie variable?

Comment: Yes. (If you're using the same domain for ajax & site)

Comment: All the Apache servers are using the same domain (e.g. .domain.com) But the verification of the login happens on Apache 2, will that still be accessible for Apache 1 even though no refresh has been made?

Comment: Did you get this sorted? I have to admit I am curious why you have so many servers in different roles, why not make them all identical and load balance?

Comment: Each "server" as I described them are actually load balanced Apache clusters.. Each cluster representing their specific duty.. It's a strategy I am trying to make.. But I actually figured it out differently.. I was talking to a friend that recommended me using memcached, and i have to admit that I am pretty amazed about its functionality.. Also combined with Couchbase, it really makes the memorystored data easy and accessibly.. :) So that was the solution...

Comment: But your answer actually worked although I needed to adjust a lot of programming here and there.. But the functionality is there.. :) Thanks for your help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the problem you are having can be solved using distributed sessions.

Using memcached you can provide a central point for all session data that any connected server can share.

If you are using linux, the below code demonstrates how commenting out local file session handling, and replacing it with memcache can allow you to share session data.

```
  ~$ cat /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini | grep -i session 
  [Session] 
  ;session.save_handler = files 
  session.save_handler = memcache 
  session.save_path = "tcp://127.0.0.1:11211"
```

For an in depth explanation visit: http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/rynop/2010/09/10/using-memcached-to-run-your-sessions

Comment: You know.. It has been a while and I actually found the same solution a few weeks after posting this question, but I got to give you +1 and correct answer :), thanks mate.